# How to optimize following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, big-o

We have following algorithm:

```
while(a > b) {
     a -= c;
}
```

a, b and c are given, b and c are constants, c > 0.

Now it works in linear time.
Is it possible to speed it up, to work in logarithmic or constant time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uhm... You could try this, right (given that a, b and c are positive integers)?

```
a = (a-b)%c + b - c
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform a binary search to find the minimum `x` such that `a-x*c <= b`.